# Inheritance of composition relationship in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition

I quite often confront myself to this problem. Let's say I have these classes:

```
class B
{
  public:
    virtual std::string className(){return "B";}
};

class A
{
  public:
    A()
    : _B(new B)
    {}

    virtual std::string className(){return "A";}

    virtual void desc()
    {
      std::cout << "I am " << className() << 
        " and I own: " << _B->className() << std::endl;
    }

  protected:
    B * _B;
};
```

Then, I want to extend `A` and `B` with new information. I am sure that `SuperA` and `SuperB` have a "is-a" relationship with `A` and `B`, respectively. The straightforward way would be to do try inheritance:

```
class SuperB: public B
{
  public:
    virtual std::string className(){return "SuperB";}
}

class SuperA: public A
{
  public:
    SuperA()
    : A()
    , _superB(new SuperB)
    {}

    virtual std::string className(){return "SuperA";}

    virtual void desc()
    {
      std::cout << "I am " << className() << 
        " and I own: " << _superB->className() << std::endl;
    }
  protected:
    SuperB * _superB;
};
```

But this is obviously not good, since `SuperA` would have actually two `B`s: the one from the `A` class, and the other from its `SuperB` class. And the override of `desc` is not so elegant.

I can see that I could have setters and getters on `B*` in `A` and override them in `SuperA` to use a `SuperB` instead of a `B`, and never refer to to `B*` directly and always use the getter, but this seems a bit intrusive for `A`.

Trying to compose, i.e. having `SuperA` owning an `A*` instance does not look better either.

And it gets even harder if `A` owns not a single `B*` but a say `std::vector<B*>`.

Is this a common problem? Is there an elegant solution that I don't see for it?

Comment: Why can't you have a protected c'tor in `A` that accepts a `B` pointer? Then use it to construct the `A` sub-object of `superA` with a `superB`?

Comment: You could use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` wherever you use `_superB` in `SuperA`. Not elegant, but maybe enough for your purposes?

Comment: @StoryTeller This is a solution. This is a bit intrusive for A though.

Comment: I think one way to formulate the problem is that classes `A` and `SuperA` have two responsibilities: They adapt a `B` or `SuperB` respectively to some other interface, **and** they manage the lifetime of a `B` or `SuperB` object. You could split those responsibilities by only providing the converting ctor `A(B*)` etc., then another type that manages the lifetime of those objects.

Comment: @RedWark, that may be, but IMHO it's no more intrusive than having a protected memeber to begin with.

Comment: @StoryTeller you are right. And that the solution I end up to accept anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just have `A` have a protected constructor that takes a `B*`:

```
class A {
public:
    A()
    : _B(new B)
    { }

protected:
    A(B* b)
    : _B(b)
    { }
};
```

So that:

```
class SuperA : public A {
public:
    SuperA()
    : A(new SuperB)
    { }
};
```

Comment: I did not think of that. This solution is actually not that intrusive and supports the vector that I evoked in the latter part of my question! Thanks!